# Can the Templar (follower) actually tank Act 3 and 4 Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii

I cannot afford to equip my Templar with really good items, as I have to use all my money on my main char.

The Templar seems to do really nice in Act 1 with the gear I gave him.

This looks quite different in Act 2. Here he can only divert the enemy for a few hits until he dies. Act 3 is a disaster, he usually just dies from 1 to two hits. I need him to tank about 5-7 hits so my DH can deal the required damage without getting bothered.

Can I somehow equip him with gear that he can actually help in Act 3 and 4 or am I on my own from now on? What items should I look for?

Again the question is not: What follower should I use, but can I use the Templar with really good gear in Act 3 and 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  The armor of your follower and damage reduction is just waaaaay too low to tank anything in inferno.  Since there's no way to outfit him with armor other than a shield and what few mods you can get on jewelry, its simply not feasible.  Your best bet is to give him as much +vit and magic find gear(at least you get 20% of the mf benefit) as possible and just have him soak up damage and distract enemies with his stun.

Comment: There isn't much point in stacking Magic Find gear on him if you're using him to soak. Followers do not give you a bonus from Magic/Gold Find if they're dead.

Comment: @ickleislands true, but for the periods of time they're alive its still better than nothing.  There's really not much else to use a follower for.

Comment: His best bet is to try and get it to stay alive for as long as possible, but it's just not going to give him a noticeable effect without dropping a lot of gold on him.

Comment: that's why I said vit gear, but with bonus mf if possible

Comment: Actually the follower does give magic find when dead :o

Comment: @Domocus: I would need a source for that claim.  But if that's the case, might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Really no other source than playing. When follower is dead the magic find is still added to the character sheet.

Comment: All the follower buffs/stat increases are still applied, even when they are dead.  You can easly test this by just opening your character sheet after your follower get's stomped in inferno, and checking your mf/gf and buffs they are providing